# Why is this link not clickable on iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I am using jQuery to generate links but the links are not clickable on iOS Safari. I have not checked whether other mobile browsers have the same behaviour (links are not clickable) but on desktop browsers it works ok.

```
return '<a data-channel="'+ data +'" id="channel">'+ data.replace('#','').replace('_',' ') +'</a>';
```

What is the cause?

Answer (score 4):

I would give it an `href` attribute and test it out...mobile clients may disable anchors without them.

Comment: Adding the `href` should work. You will likely have to catch (and prevent) the default click event from propagating though.